# How to parse and evaluate a logical expression from a string in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, recursion, xforms

I'm currently parsing out xFrom XML data and displaying it in my app. Sometimes, a question input will have a logical expression attribute that I have to parse and evaluate.

At the simplest level, I’m given a string like this :

```
"selected(Key,’AnswerToQuestion’)”
```

Here, I have to parse out the Key, AnswerToQuestion and check my answer dictionary to see if the value of Key is equal to ‘AnswerToQuestion”. This is simple enough.

However in other situations, I am more complex expression such as:

```
“not(selected(Key,’AnswerToQuestion’) OR selected(Key2,’AnswerToQuestion2’))”
```

I only need to support "and", "not" and "or" statements.

I am lost on how to tackle this in an efficient way. Something tells me a simple regex won’t cut it and that I’ll need to recursively evaluate it (recursive programming has never been my strong suit). On top of that, I'm given the expression in a string format, which makes things more complicated.

Has anyone done this before? Or can offer some insight?

Thanks